# How can I use session variables across whole app

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I'd like to access session variables assigned just after login further in mysql queries on different path. However when I do that what I receive is "undefined" value. Here's my login script.

```
users.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email
    }
  })
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
          let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn: 1440
          })
          req.session.Osoba=user.Osoba
          res.send(token)
        }
      } else {
        res.status(400).json({ error: 'Taki użytkownik nie istnieje' })
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).json({ error: err })
    })
})
```

Here's session middleware (it's actually at the beggining of the main node file, just after requiring all packages and before any routes):

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))
```

Here's the line which gives me undefined.

```
app.get('/wypozyczanie', async (req, res) => {
    if (req.session) {console.log(req.session.Osoba)}
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your session middleware as bellow.

```
app.use(session({
    key: 'sess_key',
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    rolling: true,
    cookie: {
        expires: 3600000, //1 hour. Sewt as you want
        secure: false
    }
}));
```

Make sure req.session.Osoba is assigned before you are using it.

Comment: Nope. It's not working. How can I check if it is being assigned? console.log shows it fine if I do it like this: req.session.Osoba=user.Osoba console.log(req.session.Osoba) res.send(token) But maybe it's firstly sending token and doesn't save session?